# App Stops Working When Switching Activities

Tags: android, android-intent

When I switch activities from main, my application closes. When I check the log the only error I see is:

```
Emulator: coreaudio: Could not lock voice for audioOutputDeviceIOProc
Emulator: Reason: Invalid argument
```

I have changed the hw:audioOutput=no and hw:audioInput=no but things are still not working. Is it a problem with how I am using Intent? How do I get this app to stop crashing. Thanks

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton SuvButton;
    ImageButton TwoDoorButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SuvButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.SuvImageButton);


        SuvButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Suv Button Works",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ExpandableText.class));
            }
        });

        TwoDoorButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.TwoDoorImageButton);

        TwoDoorButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Two Door Button Works",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Intent intentTwo = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ExpandableText.class);
                //startActivity(intentTwo);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Do you register `ExpandableText` activity in AndroidManifest.xml?